# iterate std::vector<std::vector<char> >?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a vector like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char> > _lines;
```

I would like to iterate these vector and the vector contained within, however I'm not sure how I'd access the inside vector using the iterator of the first one?

I have the following already:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char> >::iterator first_iter = _lines.begin();

        for (; first_iter != _lines.end(); first_iter++)
        {
            (*first_iter)::iterator second_iter = (*first_iter)->begin();  // something is wrong with this? How do I get the second vector to iterate?
        }
```

Comment: you should probably store char data in std::strings and not in std::vectors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (std::vector<std::vector<char> >::iterator i = _lines.begin();
                                               i != _lines.end(); ++i)
{
    for (std::vector<char>::iterator j = i->begin(); j != i->end(); ++j)
    {
        // ... use *j
    }
}
```

If you use a modern compiler, you can use the C++0x feature `auto` to deduce the type automatically:

```
for (auto i = _lines.begin(); i != _lines.end(); ++i)
{
    for (auto j = i->begin(); j != i->end(); ++j)
    {
        // ... use *j
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify a type like this `(*first_iter)::iterator`. Just use `std::vector<char>::iterator`.

`(*first_iter)->begin()` should be `(*first_iter).begin()` (or `first_iter->begin()`). `*first_iter` is a `std::vector<char>`, not a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to spell the type of the internal iterator yourself, you cannot access a type of a class through the scope operator :: on an instance.

```
std::vector<char>::iterator second_iter = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<std::vector<char> >::iterator first_iter =_lines.begin();
for (; first_iter != _lines.end(); first_iter++) {

     std::vector<char>::iterator second_iter = (*first_iter).begin(); // or first_iter->begin()
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the way to do it:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char> >::iterator first_iter = _lines.begin();

for (; first_iter != _lines.end(); first_iter++)
{
   std::vector<char>::iterator second_iter = first_iter->begin();
}
```